# How does this Lisp code work?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This function below checks for a number in a list.  For example, here it is looking for 12.  If 12 is there, it returns `T` (true) and if it is not there, it returns  `NIL`.  I am trying to understand the syntax, but it is kind of confusing me.  Is there anyone who can help and describe what this code does in simple english?

```
1> (defun an (&rest n)
    (block nil
      (setq x (car n))
      (setq n (cdr n))
      (loop (< x 100)
      (setq n (cdr n))
      (if (eq x 2) (return (eq (car n) 12))) (setq x (1- x)))))
AN
2> (an 2 3 4 5 66 7)
NIL
3> (an 2 3 12 3 4 5)
T
```

Additional question: how does `&rest` work or what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SLIME you could do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`slime-macroexpand-all` when the point is on the last parenthesis of the block form. You would get something like this:

```
(BLOCK NIL
  (SETQ X (CAR N))                      ; save the first element in X, while declaring
                                        ; a special variable by that name
  (SETQ N (CDR N))                      ; set N to the second cons of the list
  (BLOCK NIL
    (TAGBODY
     #:G892
      (PROGN
       (< X 100)                        ; Useless, has no impact on your code
       (SETQ N (CDR N))                 ; set N to the third cons of the list
       (IF (EQ X 2)
           (RETURN-FROM NIL (EQ (CAR N) 12))) ; return from the innermost block NIL
                                        ; however, since there's no more code in the
                                        ; outermost block NIL, this will return from
                                        ; it too.
       (SETQ X (1- X)))                 ; decrement value in X. It may happen so by
                                        ; chance that, if initially X was larger than 2
                                        ; the above condition will trigger
      (GO #:G892))))
```

Perhaps, you would get better luck if you explained what were you trying to do, this function is so wrong that it is begging this question.

Comment: thanks the function is supposed to find an element or atom which is 12 in this case inside the list( 1 2 3 4 5 6 12) if its present the function should return true if not it should return nil